# How to import data from multiple pages?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small piece of code that lists links in a site.

```
Sub ListLinks()

'Set a reference to microsoft Internet Controls
Dim IeApp As InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String
Dim IeDoc As Object
Dim i As Long

Set IeApp = New InternetExplorer

IeApp.Visible = True

sURL = "http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/q_sharelookup.php"

IeApp.Navigate sURL

Do
Loop Until IeApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set IeDoc = IeApp.Document

For i = 0 To IeDoc.Links.Length - 1
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = IeDoc.Links(i).href
Next i

Set IeApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

That is very useful for listing all links in a site.  How can I loop through these URLs and import data from each one?

For instance, the first link under 'Name or Sector' is this:
http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/sharesfound.php?ssector=0533&exch=JSE&bookmark=Oil & Gas&scheme=default

There is actually nothing to import from there.  The next link has some data:
http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/sharesfound.php?ssector=0537&exch=JSE&bookmark=Oil%20-%20Integrated&scheme=default

The data from there looks like this:

```
Name    Full Name   Code    Sector
 SACOIL-N    Sacoil Holdings Ltd NPL    SCLN    0537
 ERIN    Erin Energy Corporation    ERN     0537
 BEE-SASOL       BEE - SASOL LIMITED    SOLBE1  0537
 SACOIL      SACOIL HOLDINGS LD     SCL     0537
 OANDO       OANDO PLC      OAO     0537
 OANDORIGT       OANDO PLC RIGT     OAON    0537
 MONTAUK     Montauk Holdings Ltd       MNK     0537
```

How can I import that data from each link?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty well.  It may need a bit of fine tuning, but this should be pretty darn close.

```
Sub ListLinks()

'Set a reference to microsoft Internet Controls
Dim IeApp As InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String
Dim IeDoc As Object
Dim i As Long

Set IeApp = New InternetExplorer

IeApp.Visible = True
sURL = "http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/q_sharelookup.php"
IeApp.Navigate sURL

Do
Loop Until IeApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set IeDoc = IeApp.Document
    For i = 0 To IeDoc.Links.Length - 1
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = IeDoc.Links(i).href
    Next i
Set IeApp = Nothing
Call CopyFromURL
End Sub


Public Sub CopyFromURL()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument
Dim thisClass As IHTMLElement2, thisLink As IHTMLElement
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4
Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long
row = 1
Set rng = Range("A1:A5")
For Each cell In rng

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate cell

    Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set TR_col = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TR")

    For Each TR In TR_col
        Set TD_col = TR.getElementsByTagName("TD")

col = 2
        For Each TD In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = TD.innerText
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 2
        row = row + 1
    Next

Next cell
IE.Quit
End Sub
```